pyspark dataframe look to previous column (Lag) or more higher
I am using pyspark , and i have the following dataframe :



ID
DateCOL
PRICE




1
20240301
10


1
20240301
10


1
20240302
20


1
20240303
30


1
20240304
40


1
20240305
50


1
20240305
50


1
20240305
60


1
20240305
60


1
20240306
70


2
20240306
33


2
20240307
44



and i want to generate this dataframe :



ID
DateCOL
PRICE
PREVIOUSPRICE




1
20240301
10
null


1
20240301
10
null


1
20240302
20
10


1
20240303
30
20


1
20240304
40
30


1
20240305
50
40


1
20240305
50
40


1
20240305
60
50


1
20240305
60
50


1
20240305
60
50


1
20240306
70
60


2
20240306
33
null


2
20240307
44
33



some explanation :
add the new column "PREVIOUSPRICE " :

for each group of "ID", order by "DateCOL" et "PRICE", we want to look to the previous Price
if the current price is equal to the previous one, then we should look 2 or more rows higher, until it is different

I tried with "lag" function and "unboundedPreceding" but not able to make it work

can you explain the scenario for 20240305 , for the second row it shows 40, should it be 50?

yes, here is the complexity, it should be 40, we look to the previous row, if the price of the current row is equal to the previous row then we should get the row again higher (lag, offset 2 or more), IN THIS CASE the second row 20240305 has a price 50, the previous row 20240305 has a price 50 too, then we take the price 40 with 20240304

Do you have different PRICE for the same day? Spark dataframe is un-ordered, so if you do not have any column to sort it deterministically, any solution cannot work reliably.   Currently, the sample data you show has multiple PRICE for 20240305, so there is no guarantee whether 50 or 60 comes first when using lag.
